# Log4Net, ThreadContext, and Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, logging, error-handling, log4net

I am working on a Log4Net configuration that will log all unhandled exceptions.  I need certain properties, based on user, to be added to each log entry.  I have set this up successfully in the following manner in my Application_Error event.  Here is my complete global.asax

```
Imports log4net
Imports log4net.Config

    Public Class Global_asax
        Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

        'Define a static logger variable
        Private Shared log As ILog = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType(Global_asax))

        Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            ' Fires when the application is started
            ConfigureLogging()
        End Sub

        Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
            Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
            ThreadContext.Properties("user") = User.Identity.Name
            ThreadContext.Properties("appbrowser") = String.Concat(Request.Browser.Browser, " ", Request.Browser.Version)
            If TypeOf ex Is HttpUnhandledException AndAlso ex.InnerException IsNot Nothing Then
                ex = ex.InnerException
            End If
            log.Error(ex)
            ThreadContext.Properties.Clear()
        End Sub

        Private Sub ConfigureLogging()
            Dim logFile As String = Server.MapPath("~/Log4Net.config")
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(New System.IO.FileInfo(logFile))
            log4net.GlobalContext.Properties("appname") = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetName.Name
        End Sub
    End Class
```

This appears to be working fine.  However, I have some questions that I am unable to answer.

Is the way that I am adding the user specific properties, via the threadcontext, correct?  Will this always log the correct information, even under load?  When would you use threadlogicalcontext?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not safe to load request-specific values into `ThreadContext` like that.  The reason is that ASP.NET shared threads to service requests.  It does this quite often, in fact.

You could instead use `LogicalThreadContext`, however that simply stores the values in Call Context, which is used for Remoting.

AFAIK there is no HttpContext specific context storage, so what you can do is instead assign a "value provider" instance as your thread context, and at runtime it will call .ToString() on this class to get the value.

```
public class HttpContextUserProvider
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
   }
}
```

It's less than ideal, but it works.

Comment: Just be careful if you use parallel coding since HttpContext.Current may need to be copied to any worker threads if they add to the log.

Comment: Where in global.asax.cs would you put the call to HttpContextUserProvider?

Comment: ASP.Net has a context specific storage. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx

Comment: I did put request-specific values into ThreadContext and found out that exceptions are logged with values from other requests. What kind of limitations does 'however that simply stores the values in Call Context' give? Is it valid to store request-specific values, or not?

Answer (score 5):

Ben's answer is right on.

However, like some of the other users, I was still a bit lost on how to proceed.  This [log4net Context problems with ASP.Net thread agility](http://piers7.blogspot.com/2005/12/log4net-context-problems-with-aspnet.html) post and especially this [Marek Stój's Blog - log4net Contextual Properties and ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20160429190047/http://blog.marekstoj.com/2011/12/log4net-contextual-properties-and.html) one give some more context for the problem with some excellent code examples.

I highly recommend Marek Stój's implementation, although the `ThreadContext.Properties["UserName"]` needed to be replaced with `ThreadContext.Properties["User"]` in my case.

I added a BeginRequest method to my Logger class which I call from Application_AuthenticateRequest which loads all the relevant log4net properties.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Logger.BeginRequest(Request);
}
```

And the method code:

```
public static void BeginRequest(System.Web.HttpRequest request)
{
    if (request == null) return;

    ThreadContext.Properties["ip_address"] = AdaptivePropertyProvider.Create("ip_address", IPNetworking.GetMachineNameAndIP4Address());
    ThreadContext.Properties["rawUrl"] = AdaptivePropertyProvider.Create("rawUrl", request.RawUrl);

    if (request.Browser != null && request.Browser.Capabilities != null)
        ThreadContext.Properties["browser"] = AdaptivePropertyProvider.Create("browser", request.Browser.Capabilities[""].ToString());

    if (request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        ThreadContext.Properties["User"] = AdaptivePropertyProvider.Create("user", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
}
```

I found I had to pass in the Request object instead of using `HttpContext.Current.Request` within the method.  Otherwise I would loose the user and authentication information.  Note that the `IPNetworking` class is my own so you will need to provide your own method of obtaining the client IP.  The `AdaptivePropertyProvider` class is directly from Marek Stój.

Comment: This assigns the adaptive property object to the `TheadContext` properties collection, but wasn't the initial problem that we couldn't count on that collection to persist correctly?  I think the adaptive property handler needs to be assigned as a property in the global context...

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of global object would be applicable given we are trying to log, in this case, a given web session, so the values would be contextualized by the individual thread, correct?